# How to adjust the background camera of ARCore in combination with GearVR?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore, gear-vr

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S8, Unity3D, Gear VR and ARCore.
ARCore is used as a passthrough of the smartphone camera.
Unfortunately the resolution of the background is stretched. (As you can see in the image, which should display a circle)

Does anyone know how to change the background resolution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a long time fiddling around I found an acceptable solution for me.

```
public class SetResolution : MonoBehaviour {
    public int width = 1480; //half of the Samsung S8 WQHD+ 2960x1440 resolution 
    public int height = 1440;

    void Start () {
        Screen.SetResolution(width, height, true); 
    }

    void Update () {
    }
}
```

Maybe there is a more elegant solution but it works for me.